# Using "Void" as a status instead of "Void" as an action

Tags: status, verb

I'm having trouble deciding what the status of a document should be once a user clicks the <kbd>Void</kbd> button. Using "Void" as an action seems to be common in the industry, but it feels wrong to use it as a status.

The current status options for a document are the following:

- Draft
- Pending Approval
- Awaiting Response
- Ready to Purchase
- Void
- Complete

Is there a better Status than "Void" I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use "voided" as the status. So you "unvoid" a "voided" thing and "void" an "unvoided" thing. It's weird, but that's what we do.